# Angularjs Django compare dates

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I am fetching the date from my Django backend which comes like this: `2016-03-31`
In my angular controller I want to compare it with today's date and if they are similar I want to deactivate a button.

I tried new Date() which gives me something like `Thu Mar 31 2016 08:59:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)`

How can these two dates be compared to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehhhhh... i think currently we could only do a manual formatting

see this one: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

For your reference, below is what i did though:

```
$scope.formatDate = function(date){
    var newDate = new Date(date);


    var year = newDate.getFullYear();
    var month = (newDate.getMonth() + 1).toString(); //add 1 as Jan is '0'
    var day = newDate.getDate().toString();

    month = month.length > 1? month: '0'+month;
    day = day.length > 1? day: '0'+day;

    $scope.date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the date with now you can do the following:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var compareDate = new Date('2016-03-31').getTime();

if(now > compareDate){
    //greater
}else if(now < compareDate){
    //less
}else{
   //equal
}
```

Just add what you need to the `scope` and then you could do something like:

`ng-disabled="compareDate === today"`